# What is the equivalent of JOptionPane in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to make such as [`JOptinonPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) in JSP. What is the equivalent of it JSP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, JSP runs at the webserver, produces HTML/CSS/JavaScript and sends it to webbrowser. Webbrowser retrieves HTML/CSS/JavaScript and interprets/applies/executes it. If Java/JSP has done its task right, the webbrowser should not retrieve any line of Java/JSP code. Simply because it doesn't understand it. Rightclick page and choose *View Source*. It'll become clear. Does it? :)

Now, in a webbrowser you can use JavaScript to show dialogs. E.g. an alert dialog with one button:

```
<script>alert('An alert message');</script>
```

A confirmation dialog with two buttons (which returns `true` or `false` depending on button pressed):

```
<script>var confirm = confirm('Are you sure?');</script>
```

A prompt dialog message with two buttons (which returns the input or nothing depending on button pressed):

```
<script>var input = prompt('Enter input', '');</script>
```

Just write it down in the JSP page the usual way. JSP will send it to the webbrowser.

#### See also:

- [W3schools JavaScript tutorial - popup boxes](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_popup.asp)
- [Communication between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)

---

To get a step further, you can make use of more advanced JavaScript and a good shot of CSS in combination with a HTML `<div>` element to create a nice-looking dialog. You can find [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) some examples based on jQuery UI.

Comment: Many thanx Mr BalusC , what u said here'You can find here some examples based on jQuery UI.' is what exactly what i want.